# Cross platform issue in live streaming from WOWZA server

Tags: android, ios, wowza, wowza-transcoder

We are planning to use WOWZA server for live streaming but issue we are facing is when live stream start from iOS, all iOS and android users subscribers are able to watch but when live streaming start from android, iOS users facing issue in live streaming, not able to watch as seems issue in codeco format supporting, we tried VLC, etc library to run for android user but could not help..found some third party libabries like nanocosmos woked fine but they are costly..is there anyone who used wowza server streaming on cross platform then what was used on android client??any suggestion will really appreciated.

Comment: I think wowza can encode and convert the stream into any supported format try using HLS for IOS

Comment: The codecs supported on the incoming side for transcoding are limited in Wowza; you may want to look at http://red5pro.com/ its free to try and they've got SDK's for both iOS and Android. The server also supports HLS, RTSP, and RTMP simultaneously.